# Unable to connect Azure SQL database from Spring boot using AD user

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc

I have enabled the AADAuthencationOnly and I am able to connect via SQL Server Management Studio. But when I am trying to connect the database from spring boot application but I am getting below error when I am using `com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0` or  `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.4.2.jre11`

> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalClientException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

application.yml

```
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://xz.database.windows.net:1433;database=xz;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
    username: cld.svc.AzureData.xzaadaccount@myid.onmicrosoft.com
    password: Ok0qYszsGPhM5trLIxHZBDdQbvxyJ2mnrRnbXRYN30OrCEX2nHCoqKsX
```

Spring boot Version : 2.7.8

How can I resolve this issue. If I want to use the certificates, where can i download the certificates for Azure SQL database?

Comment: The 'unable to find a valid certification path to the requested target' error typically results from encountering an untrusted certificate, such as a self-signed one. To address this, we need clarification. Can you confirm if your Azure SQL Database uses a secure TLS connection? If it does, the party responsible for this security may have the required public certificate for you to trust. You can do this by adding it to the Java TrustStore or installing it on the application server.

Comment: @m.lucas, I have added the TrustStore to cacerts, but still getting the same issue

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jdbc-with-azure-sql-server?tabs=passwordless check this document if it helps you?

Comment: @Pratik Lad, I already checked that one, but no success.